# Why does the first print statement's string gets printed in python?

Tags: python, output, python-3.6, mu

```
while True:
    print("HI , TELL YOUR NAME")
    name = input()
    if name != 'anwar':
        continue
    print("your password , please")
    password=input()
    if password != 'bull':
        break
print("access granted")
```

So the problem here is when I receive the output, I get the first print statement's string that is

---------------**output**-------------

```
HI , TELL YOUR NAME
anwar
your password , please
bull
access granted
HI , TELL YOUR NAME
```

I dont want the first statement to printed again..

where as  I look into my book and I saw that the same program prints perfectly ..

```
Python 3.6
1   while True:
2       print('Who are you?')
3       name = input()
4       if name != 'Joe':
5           continue
6       print('Hello, Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish.)')
7       password = input()
8       if password == 'swordfish':
9           break
10  print('Access granted.')
```

and the output is what I want really wanted ........

--------------**output**----------

```
Who are you?
Joe
Hello, Joe. What is the password? (It is a fish.)
swordfish
Access granted.
```

please note that the first statment "who are you?" doesn’t print at the end of the program.

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is breaking on the right password, while you are breaking if the password doesn't match. So the it will keep looping until you enter a wrong password

```
if password != 'bull':
```

should be

```
if password == 'bull':
```

to break the loop on bull

Comment: Thank-you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are testing

```
if password != 'bull':
```

while your book example uses `==` ...

Comment: Thank-you so much :)